# how to clear Hackerank Dynamic array Runtime error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, .net

I have done the coding and my few test cases got passed but the test case 2 and few more did not pass. When I ran the same code in local, I got the desired result but on HackerRank, it shows Runtime error.

Here is the question - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array/problem

Here is my solution:-

```
public static List dynamicArray(int n, List> queries) {

   List<List<int>> seqList = new List<List<int>>();

        for (int j = 0; j < n ; j++)
        {
            seqList.Insert(j, new List<int>(n-1))  ;
        }


        List<int> seqList2 = new List<int>();

        int lastAnswer = 0;
        int index;

        for (int i = 0; i < queries.Count ; i++)
        {

                index = ((queries[i][1] ^ lastAnswer) % n); 

                if (queries[i][0] == 1)
                {
                  seqList[index].Add(Convert.ToInt32(queries[i][2]));
                }

                else

                {

                int value = queries[i][2] % seqList[index].Count ;
                lastAnswer = seqList[index][value];

                    Console.WriteLine(lastAnswer);
                    seqList2.Add(lastAnswer);
                } 

        }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your complete dynamicArray function, are you returning seqList somewhere?

Comment: Yes I am returning seqList2

Answer (score 0):

A runtime error on Hackerrank can be because of uninitialized variables or because of trying to access an element in an array which is not there (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)

I'm guessing in your case because of the latter.